# In-App purchases many functionally independent subscriptions

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store, subscription

I need to create purchase system that allows user to use part of app for limited time (1 month), optimally with auto-renewal. My app is non-newsstand app.

Is there any possibility to accomplish this with auto-renewable/non-renewable subscription or should I use Consumable?

For better understanding, what I want to accomplish:
    Lets say I have Facebook app. User want to search for another users, so he buys searching option for 1 month. Week later he want to put more than 10 photos so he buys another option. At this point he have 2 functionally independent options with different end time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Set different product identifiers for each functionality you are offering. To those product identifiers based on the way you are offering give it auto-renewable/non-Consumable. You cannot use two options combined. You have to chose based on your requirement.

Comment: So all I have to do is to set different ID for each functionaliy and I can offer auto-renewable subscription for with different price/length for each of this funcionality?

Comment: Yes, exactly @JarosławKrajewski